# Logging non-exception errors

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, exception

While working on a better solution for logging (unhandled) exceptions in my application I reached a point where I would like to also log errors that are not sent to the exception handlers/delegate like

```
exceptionHandler:shouldLogException:mask:
```

There are quite a number of error message that are only logged in the console, like the famous **"I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil date?"** error you get when you, for example, run

```
[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]
```

with a nil date. This message even includes a stack trace. Another warning/errors example is:

> CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using
>   name "Andale Mono" and got font with PostScript name "AndaleMono". For
>   best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.

These messages appear in the debug console in XCode and I would like to log them to my app's log file to fix these problems.

Any idea how I can accomplish that? Capturing NSLog() (if so, how?)? Better ideas?